# Why (or when) does a template bring in its namespace?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, c++17

Here's an example:

```
#define MAKE_IT_WORK false
namespace Bob {  // Bob's project namespace
   struct DeviceFrequency {};
   extern void debugf(const char* fmt, ...);
}  // namespace Bob

namespace SSN {  // Super-Secret Namespace
   namespace debugging {
     extern int  ssn_debug;
     extern void debugf(const char* fmt, ...);
   }  // namespace debugging
}  // namespace SSN

namespace SSN::signals { // Super-Secret Namespace, project signals
   template<typename Coder> // In the example, this imports Bob's namespace
   class Frequency {
     public:
     Frequency( void )
     { using namespace ::SSN::debugging; // Why isn't this enough??
       using ::SSN::debugging::debugf;   // Or this??
       if( ssn_debug )
       #if MAKE_IT_WORK
         ::SSN::debugging::  // How can a developer predict that this is needed??
       #endif
         debugf("Frequency(%p,%zd)::Frequency\n", this, sizeof(*this));
     }
   }; // class Frequency
}  // namespace SSN::signals

struct Controller {
   SSN::signals::Frequency<Bob::DeviceFrequency> bobcon;
   Controller( void ) : bobcon() {}
}; // class Controller
```

In this example, Bob duplicates the `debugf` function because he doesn't want to have to bring the entire SSN namespace into his private one and doesn't want to be bothered with fully qualifying it every time he uses it.

The SSN developer didn't realize that a template could also import its namespace (until it happened), apparently bringing ADL lookup into play. Although ADL lookup states that using statements in namespace are ignored, why it comes into play at all doesn't make sense. It seems way too easy for one namespace to unintentionally pollute another, and way too hard to predict where this might someday occur in inline code.

It looks like (at least) whenever templates are used within a namespace, *every* namespace function reference must be fully qualified because when using templates you can't predict when a name conflict might otherwise occur. Is this correct? If so, is there any way to avoid all that extra name qualifier typing that seems to be required? Is this exposure limited to templates, or is all imported inline code somehow similarly vulnerable?

Compiling (Dirty.cpp) using gcc versions 10.2.0 and 10.2.1 (Red Hat 10.2.1-5), I got the following messages:

> ```
> make dirty 
> c++  -o Dirty.o -c S/Dirty.cpp  -D_CC_GCC -D_OS_BSD -D_HW_X86 -D_OS_LINUX -IS -IH -g -O3 -finline->functions -std=gnu++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wswitch-default -Werror
> S/Dirty.cpp: In instantiation of ‘SSN::signals::Frequency<Coder>::Frequency() [with Coder = Bob::DeviceFrequency]’:
> S/Dirty.cpp:146:32:   required from here
> S/Dirty.cpp:139:12: error: call of overloaded ‘debugf(const char [30], SSN::signals::Frequency<Bob::DeviceFrequency>*, long unsigned int)’ is ambiguous
>  139 |      debugf("Frequency(%p,%zd)::Frequency\n", this, sizeof(*this));
>      |      ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> S/Dirty.cpp:124:13: note: candidate: ‘void SSN::debugging::debugf(const char*, ...)’
>  124 | extern void debugf(const char* fmt, ...);
>      |             ^~~~~~
> S/Dirty.cpp:117:13: note: candidate: ‘void Bob::debugf(const char*, ...)’
>  117 | extern void debugf(const char* fmt, ...);
>      |
> ```

(Edited: The example has been restored to the original, now as reformatted by @1201ProgramAlarm. A modified version appears that tests examples follows in the partial answer below.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a template, ADL includes the namespaces and entities associated with the
types of the template arguments provided for template type parameters. Because the call to `debugf` includes `this` as a parameter, ADL will include `namespace Bob` because the template is instantiated with `Bob::DeviceFrequency`.

Comment: Removing `this` as a `debugf` parameter does, indeed, remove the `namespace Bob` interference. This is true even though `this` doesn't and, as far as I can tell, can't ever directly refer to namespace Bob. Using `this` elsewhere in the function has no effect on the `debugf` name lookup. I'm not a fan of ADL. I find it overly complex and surprisingly unpredictable. As I reinspect my libraries for possible ADL-induced name pollution, do I only have to look at template functions using `this` as a parameter, or are there other "gotcha's" still lurking?

Comment: @FNE ADL is necessary anyway. and it is used to call an argument-dependent function template (such as `swap`) especially for only types inside this namespace, instead of a general function like your `debugf`. you should put it outside the namespace or use the qualified name lookup in this case.

Comment: @RedFog The point is that I clearly (except to a compiler) wasn't *trying* to use ADL. It just happened, capriciously, unexpectedly. The fact that it's used and some consider it necessary is beside the point. I'm looking for advice on how to avoid using it accidentally, again. How a bare `this` can qualify as something that references a type field is beyond me. Something like `this->template_object` would seem to be required. Obviously, I'm no ADL expert. All I want to do is avoid it. What else besides the *this* parameter (and reference to template objects) do I need to look for?

Comment: @FNE Any member of the class would also cause it (so if `Frequency` had any member variables, referencing those would look for names in `Bob`). But a `SSN::signals::Frequency<int>` type would not find `Bob::debugf` during name lookup.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, not exactly correct. I've modified the example to demonstrate what I've found. `Frequency` member variable reference has no side effect. It looks to me like you have to reference a named struct or class member object rather than any object field in order for ADL to get interested in function name resolution.

Comment: See my answer, above, for additional detail on what does and does not cause ADL to occur. It also contains a way to prevent ADL once it's unwanted presence is detected. This, however, is the accepted answer because it exactly describes what (apparently undocumented) feature of ADL caused the error message I got. Without this insight, I'd still be too confused to look at it more closely.

Answer (score 0):

Updated example:

```
// Last change: 2020/10/30 11:15 EDT
#define MAKE_IT_WORK true // Modified (Example compiles)
namespace Bob {  // Bob's project namespace
   extern double thing;     // (Added for answer testing)
   struct Bar { int foo; }; // (Added for answer testing)
   struct Foo { int bar; }; // (Added for answer testing)
   extern Foo bar;          // (Added for answer testing)
   struct DeviceFrequency { double f; }; // (Modified: added "double f;")
   extern void debugf(const char* fmt, ...);
   static inline void function(DeviceFrequency& E)  // (??TRICKY inference??)
     { debugf("default function, E: %f\n", E); }
}  // namespace Bob

namespace SSN {  // Super-Secret Namespace
   namespace debugging {
     extern int  ssn_debug;
     extern void debugf(const char* fmt, ...);
   }  // namespace debugging
}  // namespace SSN

namespace SSN::signals { // Super-Secret Namespace, project signals
   template<typename Coder>
   class Frequency {
     // Note: The Function type references the template indirectly, and has
     // no purpose other than to make sure that a <Coder> function handler
     // receives a <Coder&> parameter. ADL doesn't care. It brings in the
     // Coder's namespace looking for functions to override.
     typedef std::function<void(Coder&)> Function; // (Added) Another "gotcha"
     const Function function; // This indirectly references Coder&, thus Bob

     double thing= 543.21;   // (Added) Duplicates name in namespace Bob
     double f= 123.45;       // (Added) Duplicates name in Bob::DeviceFrequency
     Bob::Foo bar{876};      // (Added) Uses Bob namespace
     struct Bar { int foo= 0x0F00; } foo; // (Added) Duplicates a Bob struct name
     struct Derived : public Bob::Foo {}; // (Added) Uses Bob namespace
     Derived secret{{671}};  // (Added) Uses Bob namespace in derived object
     struct Container { int n= 888; Bob::Bar m{999}; }; // (Added) Uses Bob namespace
     Container content;      // (Added) Uses Bob namespace in container object

     public:
     // This constructor added to demonstrate indirect template references
     Frequency( const Function& _function ) : function(_function)
     { using namespace ::SSN::debugging; // Without this, Bob::debugf is used
       ::SSN::debugging::    // Disambiguate
       debugf("Frequency::Frequency(Coder: %p,%zd)\n", &_function, sizeof(_function));

       // Drive the function, mostly just to see that it's been coded correctly
       // Note the existence of function(DeviceFrequency& E) in namespace Bob.
       // This *looks* like it might call Bob::function, but it doesn't,
       // likely because function is an object containing an operator(), a
       // std::function container.
       Coder coder{2468}; function(coder);  // (??TRICKY?? Not ADL ambiguous)
       Coder rodoc{8642}; _function(rodoc); // (??TRICKY?? Not ADL ambiguous)
       Bob::function(coder); // Just to verify it's different
     }

     Frequency( void )       // Default constructor
     { using namespace ::SSN::debugging; // Why isn't this enough??
       using ::SSN::debugging::debugf;  // Or this??
       // Answer: When ADL comes into play, using statements are ignored.
       //         Also, without the first using, Bob::debugf would be used.
       //    (Rationale unclear, but that's the way it is.)
       if( ssn_debug )
         #if MAKE_IT_WORK
           // As explained by @1201ProgramAlarm, it's the 'this' parameter that
           // brought Bob's namespace into play for ADL name resolution.
           //    (Rationale unclear, but that's the way it is.)
           ::SSN::debugging::  // How can a developer predict that this is needed??
         #endif
         debugf("Frequency(%p,%zd)::Frequency\n", this, sizeof(*this));

       // All remaining lines in Frequency added for detailed testing ============
       const void* const that= this; // Another work-around
       debugf("Frequency(%p,%zd)::Frequency\n", that, sizeof(*this)); // (Works)

       Coder coder{3.14};    // (This is a Bob::DeviceFrequency)
       debugf("Coder.f: %f\n", coder.f); // (No ambiguity)
       Bob::debugf("Coder: %f\n", coder); // *** AMBIGUOUS debugf ***

       debugf("f: %f\n", f); // (No ambiguity)
       debugf("thing: %f\n", thing); // (No ambiguity)
       debugf("Bob::thing: %f\n", Bob::thing); // (No ambiguity)
       debugf("bar.bar: %d\n", bar.bar); // (No ambiguity)
       SSN::debugging::debugf("bar: %d\n", bar); // *** AMBIGUOUS debugf ***
       Bob::debugf("this->bar: %d\n", this->bar); // *** AMBIGUOUS debugf ***
       debugf("foo.foo: 0x%3x\n", foo.foo); // (No ambiguity)
       debugf("this->foo: 0x%3x\n", this->foo); // (No ambiguity)
       debugf("Bob::bar.bar: %d\n", Bob::bar.bar); // (No ambiguity)
       Bob::debugf("Bob::bar: %d\n", Bob::bar); // *** AMBIGUOUS debugf ***
       debugf("secret.bar: %d\n", secret.bar); // (No ambiguity)
       Bob::debugf("secret: %d\n", secret); // *** AMBIGUOUS debugf ***
       debugf("content: %d\n", content); // (No ambiguity)
       Bob::debugf("content.m: %d\n", content.m); // *** AMBIGUOUS debugf ***
       // End of added lines =====================================================
     }
   }; // class Frequency

   template<typename Coder>
   struct Ugly_fix {         // Macros stop ADL lookup, remove usings
      #define debugf ::SSN::debugging::debugf
      #define ssn_debug ::SSN::debugging::ssn_debug

      Ugly_fix( void )       // Default constructor
      {  if( ssn_debug ) debugf("Ugly_fix(%p)::Ugly_fix\n", this);
         debugf("Bob::bar: %d\n", Bob::bar);
         // Bob::debugf("Bob::bar: %d\n", Bob::bar); // Syntax error
      }

      #undef debugf          // Macros (MUST BE) private
      #undef ssn_debug
   }; // struct Ugly_fix

   class Non_template { public:
     Non_template( void )
     { using namespace ::SSN::debugging;
       if( ssn_debug )
         debugf("Non_template(%p,%zd)::Non_template\n", this, sizeof(*this));
     }
   }; // class Non_template
}  // namespace SSN::signals

// Namespace: **NONE**
static struct Handler { // Note: This actually *USES* ADL to find debugf
   void operator()(Bob::DeviceFrequency& E) { debugf("E: %f\n", E); }
}  handler; // struct Handler

struct Controller {
   SSN::signals::Frequency<Bob::DeviceFrequency> bobcon;
   SSN::signals::Frequency<Bob::DeviceFrequency> robcon;
   SSN::signals::Ugly_fix<Bob::DeviceFrequency>  ugly;
   SSN::signals::Non_template non_template;

   // Note that both Frequency constructors are used.
   Controller( void ) : bobcon(), robcon(handler), ugly(), non_template() {}
}; // class Controller

// IMPLEMENTATION ============================================================
namespace SSN {
   int debugging::ssn_debug= true;
   namespace debugging {
     void debugf(const char* fmt, ...) {
       printf("SSN: ");      // (For output disambiguation)
       va_list argptr; va_start(argptr, fmt); vprintf(fmt, argptr); va_end(argptr);
     }  // debugf
   }  // namespace debugging
}  // namespace SSN

namespace Bob {
   double thing= 1122.33;    // (Added for answer testing)
   Foo    bar{732};          // (Added for answer testing)
   void debugf(const char* fmt, ...) {
     printf("Bob: ");        // (For output disambiguation)
     va_list argptr; va_start(argptr, fmt); vprintf(fmt, argptr); va_end(argptr);
   }  // debugf
}  // namespace Bob

// TEST ======================================================================
static inline int            // Number of errors encountered
   test_namespace_glitch( void ) // Test namespace glitch
{
   int errorCount= 0;        // Number of errors encountered

   printf("\ntest_namespace_glitch\n");
   Controller controller;    // (Actually drive the constructor)

   if( true ) {
     errorCount++;           // *Why* does 'this' import namespace?
     printf("Still (partially) unexplained\n");
   }

   return errorCount;
}
```

(For those who like to run code, most of the test wrappers are also included here. You only need a main program that invokes the test.)

Here are the things I know I need to look out for:

- Usage of `this` as a (bare) parameter inside of template code. (Thanks to [@1201ProgramAlarm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5231607/1201programalarm) for pointing this "feature" out.) It's easy to do this accidentally, but hard to figure out why it happened.
- Reference of an (uncontrolled) namespace named object (i.e. a struct or a class) *used as a parameter to a function* whether or not it's inside of template code. This is harder to do accidentally.
- This reference can be indirect, as in the `Frequency(const Function&)` constructor, and therefore more prone to accidental use.

This may or may not be a complete list of ADL "gotcha's." There's a lot of examples in  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl that make me dizzy reading them, but the working ones don't usually seem to be things you might do accidentally once you've been bitten by ADL.

In my opinion, ADL shouldn't occur without explicit intent. Some language keyword or signal like `[[adl]]std::swap(obj1,obj2)` should be needed to activate it. But that's just me, I guess.

I don't know or understand the rationales behind the ADL design decisions to ignore using statements and to consider a bare *this* parameter a reference to a template object. I'm sure (OK, hoping) they exist. You may be interested in Andrew Koenig's short commentary [A Personal Note About Argument-Dependent Lookup](https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/a-personal-note-about-argument-dependent/232901443), found while diving into the mysteries of ADL in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) above.

Also, for the record, I'm up-voting and accepting [@1201ProgramAlarm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5231607/1201programalarm)'s answer because he explained that the *this* parameter brought ADL into play. When looking explicitly for it, I didn't find any documentation saying this would happen. While it doesn't answer my question, "How do I prevent this from happening?" I couldn't have gotten started without it.

What does help is that you get a seemingly unexplainable "ambiguous reference" error message that let's you know something strange and bad happened. Too late and too bad for whoever has to fix the problem. Too bad for someone who doesn't think about ADL, and might have to spend an inordinate amount of time first trying to isolate the problem and even then finally have to call on stackoverflow for help because ADL's just so *weird.*

I have an ugly way to bypass ADL, shown in the `Ugly_fix` constructor. By using (ugh) macros to auto-magically fully qualify names, not only is ADL prevented but the using statements are no longer needed. This kind of macro must be temporary, undefined after use, to avoid macro namespace pollution.